# Append flow from ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, view, navigation

I'm new to swift and programming in general so I apologize in advance if I'm explaining this poorly. I'm interning on a legacy project as part of a bootcamp. And I'm trying to navigate from a menu view that is presented over an image, to another screen. I want to store a copy the image data inside an array and bring it over to the next screen. If that's possible. But I get this warning after hitting the create order button. I'm not sure how to implement the solution suggested in the console. which is as follows;

`fileprivate func fillData()
tapped at message with id: nil. idx = nil
appended flow from OrderCreateViewController
appended and setted as current controller: Optional(Bond_Agent.OrderCreateViewController)
create order with:
message: nil
files: []

2020-08-18 14:00:26.107861-0400 Bond Agent[7867:5955978] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7ff2c49b6a00> on <Bond_Agent.OrderCreateViewController: 0x7ff2c3fc7fb0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`
[the image and create order menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1v1w.jpg)

Please let me know if more context is required, thank you in advance for your time and help <3

Comment: Can you provide the code for fileprivate func fillData()?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand what you are trying to store the image on the view and access that image data in another view controller to which you are performing segue. If my understanding is correct, then you can do as below
Let say you have 2 Viewcontrollers (MainVC) where you have image and create order button and (SecondVC) which will be presented when "create order" is clicked. SO you want image data from MainVC to be accessed in SecondVC then in you can do below:

In MainVC:

```
class MainVC : UIViewController {
   var imageData : NSMutableArray = []
   ....
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    ....
    imageData.add(<UImage>)
    return cell;
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.destination is SecondVC
        {
            let vc = segue.destination as? SecondVC
            vc?.imageDataArray = imageData
        }
    }
}
```

And in SecondVC.swift, you have to declare imageDataArray as below and when you perform segue from MainVC to SecondVC this imageDataArray will now contain all the imageData array content of MainVC and you can access these:

```
 class SecondVC : UIViewController {
     var imageDataArray : NSMutableArray = []
     ...
 }
```

Comment: The app is using .xib files for views there is no main.storyboard file & Navigation is carried out by flow Coordinators, using  UIResponder, Am I able to use segues alongside it?  Sorry I'm not sure I can use your suggestion in this case, but it's good to know for future projects. Thank you :) fileprivate func fillData() is populating the chatlist where the img would be selected from to create an order.https://controlc.com/88eea563